# Mesh passing through mesh

Tags: mesh

Hi I´m new in blender and I´m trying to do a simple animation in which two persons greet each other. The problem is that the fingers of the two keep passing through each other as in the image. Is there a way to make that when one mesh or part of it touches the other it stops so it doesn´t pass through the other?

I have searched every term that I could come up with but haven´t find anything that at least gives me a hint on this.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Hello, not that I know, you need to move the bones so that the meshes don't interact

Comment: The way to do that is by doing rigid body simulation with collision detection, but you don't use that approach in animation.  Rather, as @moonboots said, it's up to the animator to move the bones so that it doesn't happen.